# Can I get assistance with Redis commands that do the following?

Tags: python, java, sql, redis, tags

commands of Redis to do the following:

1. Store this sentence in a string: “This is Database Systems.”
2. Display the length of the string
3. Add the sentence “The course code is NDBS742” to the end of the string so it reads as “This is Database Systems. The course code is NDBS742.”
4. Automatically delete the string from the database in 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Redis commands for your scenario - to run these from a programming language you'll need to map them to a Redis Client, such as redis-py (https://github.com/redis/redis-py) for Python.  This is pretty straightforward as these map Redis commands to functions of the same name and the order of arguments is generally the same.

Storing a string:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set mystring "This is Database Systems."
OK
```

Get length of a string:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> strlen mystring
(integer) 25
```

Append sentence to the end of the string:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> append mystring " The course code is NDBS742."
(integer) 53
127.0.0.1:6379> get mystring
"This is Database Systems. The course code is NDBS742."
```

Expire the key after 60 seconds:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> expire mystring 60
(integer) 1
```

All commands documented at https://redis.io/commands/

With `redis-py` (`pip install redis`) your code looks like this:

```py
import redis

# Connect to Redis...
r = redis.Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, decode_responses=True)

# Store a string.
r.set("mystring", "This is Database Systems.")

# Get the length of the string.
print(f"Length: {r.strlen('mystring')}")

# Append sentence to the end of the string.
r.append("mystring", " The course code is NDBS742.")

# Get the value of the string back.
print(f"mystring: {r.get('mystring')}")

# Expire the key after 60 seconds.
r.expire("mystring", 60)
```

Let's run that:

```
$ python main.py
Length: 25
mystring: This is Database Systems. The course code is NDBS742.
```

Tested with Python 3.10.7, redis-py 4.5.3